# How to run 2 sites with Django channels on the same host?

Tags: django, django-channels

I tried to start 2 daphne servers and 2 workers with supervisord.
But sometimes requests from site #1 are on worker #2 and requests from site #2 are on worker #1.

Should I use different Redis servers? Rly?
Or am I missing some parameter in settings?

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('{{redis_server}}', 6379)],
        },
        'ROUTING': '{{app}}.routing.channel_routing',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need unique `prefix` parameter:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
            "prefix": "gradcam",
        },
        "ROUTING": "gradcam.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```